# Sort object based on Enum List

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an Object with multiple properties and want to sort based on specific enum list.

**Below is Object**

```js
const ArratOfobj = [
   { id: 3, ShortType: "LocationWorn", ImageType: "B" },
   { id: 2, ShortType: "SipStillLife", ImageType: "D" },
   { id: 1, ShortType: "SipStillWorn", ImageType: "M" },
   { id: 4, ShortType: "LocationLife", ImageType: "M" },
];
```

**Enum Order**

```html
  const order= {
            '0': { ShortType: "SIP Still Life", ImageType: "M"},
            '1': { ShortType: "SIP Still Life", ImageType: "B" },
            '2': { ShortType: "Location Still Life", ImageType: "M" },
            '3': { ShortType: "Location Still Life", ImageType: "B" }          
        }
```

**Expected Output **

```js
[
   { id: 2, ImageType: "D", ShortType: "SipStillLife" }, 
   { id: 4, ImageType: "M", ShortType: "LocationLife" }, 
   { id: 1, ImageType: "M", ShortType: "SipStillWorn" }, 
   { id: 3, ImageType: "B", ShortType: "LocationWorn" }
]
```

Comment: You object is formatted wrong

Comment: I assume you mean TypeScript not JavaScript? Please set the tag appropriately. Also has nothing to do with jquery or JSON.

Comment: When asking for help, please explain what you have tried and the results that you observed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't create an object by this way, but I guess you meant an array ob objects.

there is how you could sort this array by using enum order :

```
      const ArratOfobj = [
          { id: 3, ShortType: "LocationWorn", ImageType: "B" },
          { id: 2, ShortType: "SipStillLife", ImageType: "D" },
          { id: 1, ShortType: "SipStillWorn", ImageType: "M" },
          { id: 4, ShortType: "LocationLife", ImageType: "M" },
        ];
        
        const enum Order {
          SipStillLife = 0,
          LocationLife = 1,
          SipStillWorn = 2,
          LocationWorn = 3,
        }
        
        const sortedArray = ArratOfobj.sort((a, b) => {
          return Order[a.ShortType] - Order[b.ShortType];
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Chadjaa

My enum order is bit change now if it possible can we get in below order using below const order variable

  const order= {
            '0': { ShortType: "SIP Still Life", ImageType: "M"},
            '1': { ShortType: "SIP Still Life", ImageType: "B" },
            '2': { ShortType: "Location Still Life", ImageType: "M" },
            '3': { ShortType: "Location Still Life", ImageType: "B" }          
        }

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: I have revised my original stack

Comment: What if i have to sort via ImageType as well in M,B, D order